# How to easily copy columns and rows from the tables of phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am always requested to handle the processing of documents, so I have to deal with copying data from the tables of phpMyAdmin to the Excel file. Is there any ways to easily copy columns and rows from the tables of phpMyAdmin to a text file?

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround *from any browser*:

- Make sure the content of the cells is visible and not truncated.
- Highlight and copy the whole table,
- paste in any text editor that supports tables (ie. Winword, Excel, LibreOffice.. etc.)
- Highlight the column needed and copy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install a chrome extension which is called ColumnCopy.
2. Enter the following command in the SQL query section in phpMyAdmin, and then click go:

`DESCRIBE "name_of_table";`

3. Highlight the word `field`, and then right-click and choose ColumnCopy, and then click to copy this column.
4. Copy the result to the excel file or anywhere you want.